# how to preg_replace specific word in P

Tags: php, preg-replace

i wanna change 1 word in my P tag, how can i change the specific word in p tag?

> i need to replace 1 word in this tag.

```
  $tehra='/word/';
    echo preg_replace($tehra, 'word i want to change', 'my paragraph',1);
```

Comment: The `'my paragraph'` string has no `word` in it.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex is a hard job](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/372239)
HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score -1):

You have the replacement and subject back to front

```
  $tehra='@(word)@';
  echo preg_replace( $tehra, 'my paragraph', 'The sentence with the word i want to change' );
```

Will yield:

```
The sentence with the my paragraph i want to change
```